# jquery attr shows undefined when alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

html

```
<div id="a">df</div>
```

jquery

```
alert($(this).attr('id'));
```

The value I want to be alerted is a but i get undefined

http://jsfiddle.net/110y0uux/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up the selector. With `this` you are selecting the `window` object, which has no attr `id` so you are getting undfined.

You have to select your `div` element with the specific attr

Try:

```
alert($('div').attr('id'));
```

Comment: @user1673591 What do you mean two ids? Show the html markup

Comment: I think he means if multiple div's exist. @user1673591 you need to research JS scope and get a sense of what `this` means.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$(this)` to `$("#a")`

```
alert($("#a").attr('id'));
```

See [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/110y0uux/2/)

Answer (score 1):

This is because no callback function is being executed for `<div id="a">` on page load, therefore `$(this)` is undefined. You need to display the attr of `<div id="a">`, this is how you should do it:

```
alert($('#a').attr('id'));
```

or

```
alert($('div').attr('id'));
```

Comment: `$(this)` is not undefined. It refers to a jQuery collection containing the `window` object.

Comment: I wanted to say "callback function". :) My bad.

Answer (score 1):

"this" does not point at your div, it points at the javascript function in which you operate.

Try adding a selector:

```
$('#a').attr('id')
```

will return 'a' in this case...

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show all ids of many divs

```
$('div').each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` have the context of whole window in document ready event and not div element you are looking for. Use correct selector to target the element:

```
$('#a').attr('id');
```